# Mariadb 10.2/MySQL 5.7 index condition pushdown on partitioned tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, partitioning

In MySQL 5.7.3 index condition pushdown is also working on partitioned tables as stated here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations.html.

Previously, index condition pushdown was not supported for partitioned tables. This limitation was removed in MySQL 5.7.3.

Can't find any information about MariaDB 10.2. I know it is in RC stage but maybe somebody knows about it.

In 10.1 without partitioning:
Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort

In 10.1 with partitioning on:
Extra: Using where; Using filesort

Thx

Comment: Nothing in the changelogs through 10.2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for ICP on partitioned tables was added on this MySQL commit:

- https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commit/67d2e4ef917e49b0c14cee50e47a498f3f3d95d1

You can check reliably if there is support for in a particular version of MySQL or MariaDB by running [the corresponding test](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/67d2e4ef917e49b0c14cee50e47a498f3f3d95d1/mysql-test/suite/parts/t/partition_icp.test).

**I do not see such code backported on [MariaDB's 10.2-tagged git](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.2/sql/ha_partition.h) nor on the offered source downloads.**

However, the code doesn't look like insanely crazy, so I would suggest to file a ticket on [MariaDB's Jira](https://jira.mariadb.org/) and ask to backport it. I have searched it briefly and failed to see a similar request. I am a heavy MariaDB and partitioning user and that would be indeed a nice feature to have.

Comment: Please comment here if you do it with the ticket number- otherwise, I will file it myself.